# No module named '_cffi_backend'

Tags: python

Это `py` скрипт сайта
При попытке запустить скрипт через python3.7 web.py,
генерируется данное исключение:

```
  File "web.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography import fernet
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/fernet.py", line 17, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, padding
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py", line 13, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding import lib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

как можно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо установить библиотеку cffi. Выполните в консоле следующую команду:

```
python3 -m pip install cffi
```

Если эта команда не подойдет, тогда вот еще несколько вариантов как это у вас может устанавливаться:

```
pip install cffi
pip3 install cffi
python -m pip install cffi
python3 -m pip3 install cffi
python -m pip3 install cffi
```

Конечно же, для выполнения этих команд у вас должен быть установлен pip.
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/